# Jquery Mobile & Jquery UI CSS issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Ok, im NOT a desginer and my CSS skills suck.
So I have a styling issue with buttons\submit

On most of my pages im using jquery mobile and jquery UI.
The problem is I want to apply jquery mobile style to particular buttons\submit and not jquery UI.

So by default jquery UI is applying its style to the button, but I want to use jquery mobile.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

[image]

how to tell that submit to use jquery mobile css? (I still need to use both styles on the page, just want to tell the button to use the mobile style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read the [documentation for buttons](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/buttons/).

As per the documentation, all following code will generate jQuery mobile style button

```
<a href="#" data-role="button">Anchor</a>
<form>
    <button>Button</button>
    <input type="button" value="Input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

If it is not working, the reference to the `jquery-UI` would be the culprit.

Comment: Yeah I know its a Jquery-UI CSS issue, it overides the jquery mobile css. however this will work <a href="#" data-role="button">Anchor</a>

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried:

```
<input type="button" value="Input">
```

If it does not work, you might have an issue somewhere else on the page.